# Soapclient parse result

Tags: soap, symfony

I call to a Web Service from my symfony2 controller and this is the result I´ve got:

```
object(stdClass) Data [EstadoHabitacionesFechasResult]: object(stdClass) Data [any]: string(5632) "<xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="NewDataSet"><xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="TablaEstadoHabitacion" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="TablaEstadoHabitacion"><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name="IdHabitacion" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="FechaEntrada" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/><xs:element name="FechaSalida" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"><DocumentElement xmlns=""><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>1</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>23/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>31/12/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>2</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>23/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>29/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion3" msdata:rowOrder="2" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>2</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion4" msdata:rowOrder="3" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>3</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion5" msdata:rowOrder="4" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>3</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion6" msdata:rowOrder="5" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>4</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion7" msdata:rowOrder="6" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>5</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion8" msdata:rowOrder="7" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>5</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion9" msdata:rowOrder="8" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>6</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion10" msdata:rowOrder="9" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>6</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion11" msdata:rowOrder="10" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>7</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>25/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>28/05/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion12" msdata:rowOrder="11" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>7</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion13" msdata:rowOrder="12" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>7</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion14" msdata:rowOrder="13" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>8</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>25/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>28/05/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion15" msdata:rowOrder="14" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>8</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion16" msdata:rowOrder="15" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>9</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>25/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>28/05/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion17" msdata:rowOrder="16" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>9</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>01/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion18" msdata:rowOrder="17" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>9</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>29/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>01/07/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion19" msdata:rowOrder="18" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>10</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>25/05/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>28/05/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion><TablaEstadoHabitacion diffgr:id="TablaEstadoHabitacion20" msdata:rowOrder="19" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted"><IdHabitacion>10</IdHabitacion><FechaEntrada>02/06/2012</FechaEntrada><FechaSalida>03/06/2012</FechaSalida></TablaEstadoHabitacion></DocumentElement></diffgr:diffgram>"
```

Is there any easy way to access to the data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to use classmap option of [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php)?