# Parsing response from the WSDL using PHP

Tags: php, parsing, soap, wsdl, curl-multi

I'm very sorry if I made a wrong title, I'm not familiar with SOAP response and types of it. But I guess it's a WSDL response, at least I got it from WSDL link...

I have a following url
http://somedomain.com/j.svc?wsdl

And after I made a request using curl_multi I got the following response. The response was shortened to two results so it would be easier to read

The response is as following:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetJourneyListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <GetJourneyListResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DreamFlightWCF" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <a:Journey>
                 <a:FromAirport>LHR</a:FromAirport>
                 <a:TotalPrice>146</a:TotalPrice>
              </a:Journey>
              <a:Journey>
                 <a:FromAirport>LHR</a:FromAirport>
                 <a:TotalPrice>155</a:TotalPrice>
              </a:Journey>
           </GetJourneyListResult>
      </GetJourneyListResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Is there any chance to parse the result using PHP? I made lots of searches including StackOverflow and here what I managed to find.

To parse the above response I can use following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('flight','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DreamFlightWCF');
   foreach ($xml->xpath('//flight:Journey') as $item){
     print_r($item);
   }
```

It seems that the above PHP code piece is correct by partially. I get the correct amount of "Journey"s but the $item by its own is empty.

Any solutions? Please don't advise to use SoapClient to retrieve the result. I can't move from curl_multi. I already have the result and I need to parse it. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$soap_request  = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
      $soap_request .= "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope\" soap:encodingStyle=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding\">\n";
      $soap_request .= "  <soap:Body xmlns:m=\"http://www.example.org/stock\">\n";
      $soap_request .= "    <m:GetStockPrice>\n";
      $soap_request .= "      <m:StockName>IBM</m:StockName>\n";
      $soap_request .= "    </m:GetStockPrice>\n";
      $soap_request .= "  </soap:Body>\n";
      $soap_request .= "</soap:Envelope>";

      $header = array(
        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
        "Accept: text/xml",
        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
        "Pragma: no-cache",
        "SOAPAction: \"run\"",
        "Content-length: ".strlen($soap_request),
      );

      $soap_do = curl_init();
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ecc6unitst.kaisa.com:8000/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/bndg_386D2B5BD851F337E1000000AC1264E4/wsdl11/allinone/standard/document?sap-client=400" );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "EBALOBORRP:welcome1");
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,        10);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $soap_request);
      curl_setopt($soap_do, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $header);
      $str = curl_exec($soap_do);
      if(curl_exec($soap_do) === false) {
        $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($soap_do);
        curl_close($soap_do);
        print $err;
      } else {
        curl_close($soap_do);
        var_dump($str);
        print 'Operation completed without any errors';
      }
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, and welcome to the community! Your answer would definitely benefit from an explanation and some more detail in how your solution works.

Answer (score -1):

First try [Parsing SOAP response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315526/parsing-soap-response) then try [Google](https://www.google.pl/search?q=PHP+SOAP+response).