# parse XML with simplexml_load_string()

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following xml DataSet which comes from an API I have to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://examplesite.com/WebRes">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="BuildingInfo">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID_Building" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuildingInfo diffgr:id="BuildingInfo1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ID_Building>333</ID_Building>
        <Name>Example Building Name</Name>
        <Description />
      </BuildingInfo>
    </NewDataSet>
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuildingInfo diffgr:id="BuildingInfo1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ID_Building>334</ID_Building>
        <Name>Example Building Name2</Name>
        <Description />
      </BuildingInfo>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

The problem with this one is that if I do the following:

```
<?php $result = simplexml_load_string( $xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', 0, 'xs' );

echo ($result ? 'Valid XML' : 'Parse Error'), PHP_EOL;
print_r( $result );
```

The result is:

```
Parse Error
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
```

As a fallback solution I used:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct( $p, $xml, $result, $index );
xml_parser_free( $p );
```

Which is working just fine.

The other problem is that from the same API I also have responses like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfRoomTypeBuildingsDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://examplesite.com/WebRes">
  <RoomTypeBuildingsDetails>
    <ID_RoomType>123</ID_RoomType>
    <RoomTypeName>Post Name</RoomTypeName>
    <RoomTypeDescription>This is the description</RoomTypeDescription>
    <GuestMax>2</GuestMax>
  </RoomTypeBuildingsDetails>
</ArrayOfRoomTypeBuildingsDetails>
```

Which work perfectly with the `simplexml_load_string()` function. That means I am using XML Parser for some of the responses and the `simplexml_load_string()` for the others which is not very easy to maintain.

The question here is: is there any way to parse both of the response types using `simplexml_load_string()`? or should I just switch to the XML Parser or DOMDocument or other similar library?

**NOTE:** from the first XML snippet, I am only interested in pulling the contents from the `NewDataSet` node.

Let me know if you need any more details. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to not use `simplexml_load_string()` but to parse it by creating a new SimpleXMLElement. It is still not using `simplexml_load_string()` but it allows me to use `SimpleXMLElement` to handle it.

**My Test XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://examplesite.com/WebRes">
  <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="BuildingInfo">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ID_Building" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Description" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuildingInfo diffgr:id="BuildingInfo1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ID_Building>333</ID_Building>
        <Name>Example Building Name</Name>
        <Description />
      </BuildingInfo>
    </NewDataSet>
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
      <BuildingInfo diffgr:id="BuildingInfo1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
        <ID_Building>334</ID_Building>
        <Name>Example Building Name2</Name>
        <Description />
      </BuildingInfo>
    </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

**My PHP Code**

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($quote_response);
$sxe->registerXPathNamespace('d', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1');
$result = $sxe->xpath("//NewDataSet");

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($result[0] as $title) {
    print_r($title);
}
echo "</pre>";
```

**The Result**

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [ID_Building] => 333
    [Name] => Example Building Name
    [Description] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Be careful checking for parse errors. An empty SimpleXMLElement may resolve to `false`, and if your XML contains no text or only contains namespaced elements your error check may be wrong. Always use `=== false` when checking for parse errors.

Use this instead:

```php
echo ($result !== false ? 'Valid XML' : 'Parse Error'), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question I really need an answer to is: can this be achieved with `simplexml_load_string()` ? I already managed to parse it and use the details using XML Parser. Your solution works but it does not answer my question.

Comment: that does return as "Valid XML". And that might be exactly because of the `NewDataSet` nodes children of `diffgr:diffgram`. So, XML is valid. Is it possible to parse it using `simplexml_load_string()`? The `var_dump`ed response for the test XML is: `object(SimpleXMLElement)[917]` when doing: `var_dump simplexml_load_string( $xml );`

Comment: I will try this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315526/parsing-soap-response

Comment: Good luck. simplexml_* is a little bit "limited" if you have very complex xml files. I would recommend using `DOMDocument`, because of the better namespace support.

Comment: I managed to do it using that other question. Thanks for the help anyway! I am stuck to this library because of legacy code. It will be rewritten some time soon but the need to do this is right now.